# Howto get OpenUI5 Binding Information

Tags: javascript, sapui5

I need to figure out what objects within a OpenUi5 JSONModel are bound to at least one UI component.

I want to check what objects are bound of the model and then get only new values of the bound objects from an embedded device. With other words I do not want to get all available information of a embedded device via web request if some of them are currently not visible / bound on the Ui.

Does anybody have an idea how I could figure this out using javascript.

I already saw that the JSONModel has a property called aBindings that lists all current UiBindings, but I wonder if this is the right way to get that information.

Thanks!

Comment: Are you intending to do this "live" based on the current bindings of the model, or are you trying to figure out an efficient way to analyse an existing app?

Comment: Hi Jorg, I want to poll in the background of the app the required data from an embedded device via http requests. But I do not want to read all data from the device but only that information that is bound within the Ui.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like this is your first question here, so welcome to StackOverflow!

Although it is expected that you already try out the code for which you seem to have issues and then post it here with the errors or expected results, I will still try to help you out.

To get answers to your question, I would suggest you to read through the **Data Binding** section under **Get Started: Setup and Tutorials** of the [SAPUI5 Demokit](https://sapui5.hana.ondemand.com/#/topic/e5310932a71f42daa41f3a6143efca9c). This includes,

- Creating a model
- Property binding
- Binding paths and formatting values

Once you get the basics right, you will see that with the concept of *Two-way Binding*, the model is already updated with the new values that you are looking for, if it's changed in the UI and vice-versa.

Also, if you are looking for a particular object or property, you can directly query the model instead of worrying about to which control it is binded.

For example `this.getView().getModel("myModel").getProperty("/view/visible")` will return the current value of the property "visible" regardless of which control it is binded to.

If my answer totally misses your question, please elaborate on your concerns and we can explore it further.

Comment: Hi, thanks for your support. I read and so far understood the data binding part of the tutorials.
Binding to a JSON model also works fine.
The objects within my model represent current values of a connected embedded device, e.g. the current temperature of the device.
Now I only want to poll those current values of the embedded device where the corresponding object within the JSON model is bound to a Ui component as the bandwidth to my embedded device is quite limited and I cannot update all the values every second.

Comment: So I wonder if there is something like this.getView().getModel("myModel").getBindings() to figure out which objects are bound within the Ui and therefore I have to ask the embedded device for the current values.

Example: If the current temperature is bound within the Ui and the current pressure not, then I will poll only the current temperature from the device every second and not the current pressure.

Comment: @Mortimer76 if you have a UI element with a property that is bound to your Model then instead of asking the UI element for the bindings it always easier to get the Model property that is bound to that element by using `this.getView().getModel("myModel").getProperty("/your-property")`